# How do I covert this date format to epoch?

Tags: linux, bash, date

I know the command is `date +%s -d "xxx"`

But how do I convert `11/03/2018 02:44:58` to epoch ?

```
root@AngelBeats:~# date +%s -d "11/03/2018 02:44:58"
date: invalid date '11/03/2018 02:44:58'
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: For Linux

```
date --date="11/03/2018 8:15:00" +"%s"
```

> 1520736300

---

This should do it.(For OSX Systems)

```
date -j -f "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" "11/03/2018 8:15:00" +"%s"
```

> 1520736300

The "-f" specifier can be used to set the format.

Comment: Should be `date -j -f "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" "11/03/2018 8:15:00" +"%s"` to get the epoch.

Comment: @codeforester my bad, didn't see. Thanks a lot. Edited

Comment: `date: invalid option -- 'j'
Try 'date --help' for more information.` 
I'm using manjaro

Comment: try this: ` date --date="11\03\2018 8:15:00" +"%s"

Answer (score 1):

`-j` is for BSD systems.  On Linux, use this:

```
date -d "11/03/2018 8:15:00" +"%s"
```